# Getting framework header file not found error inside static library from objective C project

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, static-libraries, importerror, file-not-found

I have created a static library(lib_A) which has two files(lib.h & lib.m) & uses two frameworks(framework_B & framework_C). Every thing is in objective C.
lib.h has a line `#import <framework_B/framework_B.h>`
I have created an objective C project(App_D) and linked the library(libA).
I have installed the frameworks(framework_B & framework_C) in my project(App_D) using Pod.
I am trying to run my project(App_D), but build fails every time & I am getting 'framework_B/framework_B.h' file not found error in lib.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the following line in the package.json of react native library project-

> "rnpm": {
>           "ios": {
>             "sourceDir": "./ios"
>           }
>         }

2. Set the framework search path of the library project-

> $(SRCROOT)/../../../ios/Pods/3rd_party_framework_folder_name

3. Installing the pod files to the application's xcode project.
4. Drag the the 3rd party framework file into the Frameworks group of the application's Xcode's Project Navigator. Select Create groups for any added folders and deselect Copy items into destination group's folder.